# Seagate IronWolf 8TB SMART data DOA?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I bought two Seagate IronWolf 8TB and both of them seems ok, but 1 is making a little bit more noise on spin-up/boot-up... a little clicking sound.

I read/write 70-100mb/s with this HDD but SMART report low raw_read_error_rate:
78, Worst 64, Thresh: 44.

the other one looks good with 100,100, 44.

Should I be worried and return it? Or is it safe to use in my Synology? (SHR1)

I contacted Seagate for fun and they suggested to run SeaTools for DOS (I'm under linux obviously), but it seems like it's running a basic "long" SMART test. Nothing special there.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you check what does the SMART attributes say about this particular HDD if you run the manufacturer's brand-specific tool, @Jay, just like their support suggested. If the HDD fails any of the Short or Long tests, then you should definitely be worried. If clicking noises are present, then it's also possible that software diagnostic tools might not be able to detect the issue, if it's hardware-related. 
I'd strongly recommend you backup all your data from the NAS. If the issue is physical damage, then I'd definitely consider replacing the HDD. Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To the extent you consider the reporting of Backblaze as reasonably reliable you should return the drives forthwith.  Backblaze's claim of 2016 QTR 3; which includes the period between 07/01/2016 and 09/01/2016, indicates that the Seagate 8TB HDD ST800DM002 had a 1.46% failure rate over 5120 drives.

This failure rate may not seem horrible; however, consider the other Seagate failure rates. The ST4000DX000 4TB drive had a 10.20% failure rate over 192 drives. The ST4000DM000 4TB drive had a 3.18% faiure rate over 34,744 drives.

If we grant more weight to the ST4000DM000 stats, based on the large volume of drives, coupled with issues you are experiencing out of the box, then wisdom suggests that you should return the drives immediately.

Please see the following table for more information:
[image]

[Source](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/blog_q3_2016_stats_table_1.jpg)

Comment: Your source link isn't exactly short.  So what portion of your link is relevant?  Can you cite and quote the information?  Your answer isn't very helpful, if the link stops working, so consider improving your answer.

Comment: How about this chart?

Comment: It's your answer.  It's your task to make your answer into something other than an answer that contains a link.

Answer (score 0):

That data doesn't include Seagate IronWolf drives.

All 6 of my 8TB Seagate IronWolf drives show large: raw_read_error_rate numbers in SMART.
All 6 also show no SMART errors, nor does the synology NAS they are in show any errors.
Seagate disks report this data differenty, as in, the total number of reads/seeks, and EEC corrections.

As per this link:
http://www.users.on.net/~fzabkar/HDD/Seagate_SER_RRER_HEC.html

Comment: I strongly suggest you quote and cite the relevant information

Comment: I already freely admit that I am absolutely not relevant.  Doesn't change my suggestion on how to improve your answer